# Query - Use LEFT, RIGHT, INNER or UNION

Tags: sql, join

I have a database with 9 tables and I need to create a suitable view that looks at all tables.[image: ERD Diragram]

The query I have for the left hand side of the ERD Diagram is working ok for the `County`, `Country`, `CustomerType` and `Associations`. I also have the code for `Accounts` working (I think), however when I start to add in the `AccountType` table, it doesn't recognize the `AccountTypeID` in the `Accounts` table.

So now I have two Queries that work but I need to join the two queries in order to see all the data to create the view. Query 1 had all the data (using multiple joins) for all the tables that interacts with the Customer Table and Query 2 has all the data (using multiple joins) for all the tables that interact with the `Accounts` Table.

Query for left hand side:

```
SELECT
    Cus.CustomerId,
    Cus.FirstName,
    Cus.LastName,
    Cty.CountyName,
    Cry.CountryName,
    Cut.CustomerType,
    Ass.AssociationType,
    Ass.CustomerId1,
    Ass.CustomerId2,
    Acc.AccountId
FROM
    Customers Cus
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
   Cty.CountyId,
   Cty.CountyName
FROM 
    County Cty
WHERE 
    Cty.IsDeleted = 0) 
AS 
    Cty 
ON 
    Cus.CountyId = Cty.CountyId
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
    Cry.CountryId,
    Cry.CountryName
FROM 
    Country Cry
WHERE 
    Cry.IsDeleted = 0) 
AS 
    Cry 
ON 
    Cus.CountryId = Cry.CountryId
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
    Cut.CustomerTypeId,
    Cut.CustomerType
FROM 
    CustomerTypes Cut
WHERE 
    Cut.IsDeleted = 0) 
AS 
    Cut 
ON 
    Cus.CustomerTypeId = Cut.CustomerTypeId
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
    Ass.AssociationId,
    Ass.AssociationType,
    Ass.CustomerId1,
    Ass.CustomerId2
FROM 
    Associations Ass
WHERE 
    Ass.IsDeleted = 0) 
AS 
    Ass 
ON 
    Cus.AssociationId = Ass.AssociationId
RIGHT JOIN
(
SELECT
    Acc.AccountId,
    Acc.CustomerId
FROM
    Accounts Acc
WHERE 
    Acc.IsDeleted = 0) 
AS 
    Acc 
ON 
    Cus.CustomerId = Acc.CustomerId
WHERE 
    Cus.IsDeleted = 0
```

QUERY for right hand side.

```
SELECT
    Acc.AccountId,
    Acc.CustomerId,
    Act.AccountType,
    Tra.TransactionType,
    Sec.SecurityType
FROM
        Accounts Acc
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
    Act.AccountTypeId,
        Act.AccountType
FROM
        AccountType Act
WHERE 
    Act.IsDeleted = 0) 
AS 
    Act 
ON 
    Acc.AccountTypeId = Act.AccountTypeId
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
    TransactionId,
    TransactionType
FROM 
    Transactions Tra
WHERE 
    Tra.IsDeleted = 0) 
AS 
    Tra 
ON 
    Acc.TransactionId = Tra.TransactionId
RIGHT JOIN
(
SELECT
    SecurityId,
    SecurityType
FROM 
    Securities Sec
WHERE 
    Sec.IsDeleted = 0) 
AS 
    Sec 
ON 
    Acc.SecurityId = Sec.SecurityId
WHERE 
    Acc.IsDeleted = 0
```

Any ideas? Thanks Anthony.

Comment: So now I have two Queries that work but I need to join the two queries in order to see all the data to create the view. Query 1 had all the data (using multiple joins) for all the tables that interacts with the Customer Table and Query 2 has all the data (using multiple joins) for all the tables that interact with the Accounts Table. Please help.

Comment: This is for a college assignment.